# Laravel last method

Tags: laravel, methods

Something strange is happening when I call my controller method:

```php
public function placeOrder()
{
    $user = JWTAuth::toUser();
    if ($user->orders->isEmpty()) {
        Order::create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'status_id' => '1', 'draft' => false]);
    }
    //Order::create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'status_id' => '1', 'draft' => false]);

    $input = Input::except('token', 'condiments');
    $input['order_id'] = $user->orders->last()->id;
    return $user->orders->last();
}
```

So if user doesn't have an order, create it.

For the sake of the argument, my user has 5 orders, and I want to return the last one. It works, I get order no. 5 returned. However, if I uncomment the order creation line (after the if clause), it should create an order every time the method is called...which it does. However, I always get the order before last returned. So I create 6th, but get 5th back...create 35th, get 34th back?

Does anyone know why that might be?

**EDIT:**

If it means something...the method gets triggered from Ionic mobile app with POST method on route

**EDIT2:**
JWTAuth is causing the issue...when I return user as `User::find(1)` it gets updated accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must insert the data as related model (see [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models)).

```php
$order = new Order(['user_id' => $user->id, 'status_id' => '1', 'draft' => false]);

$order = $user->orders()->save($order);
```

Now you can return the new order with `return $order;`
or you will need to refresh your model `$user->load('orders');`

Comment: It doesn't change it. When I create it, it gets created okay, I checked in DB